# Does svn merge return a return code if success/fail?

Tags: python, svn

I am using the following python commands to automatically merge and commit files

```
p = subprocess.Popen("svn merge ...")
p.communicate()

if(no conflict)
    p = subprocess.Popen("svn commit..."
else
    Abort script
```

What is the best way to stop script if conflict occurs? I would like to suppress the merge output also if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn merge` will prompt you something like this if there are any merge conflicts:

```
Conflict discovered in 'foo'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options:
```

You can skip the prompt using the `--non-interactive` flag:

```
svn merge --non-interactive URL WC
```

(Note that `--not-interactive` can be used for other SVN commands as well.)

This will allow the merge to continue without user input, but will mark any files that have conflicts; you will have to manually resolve conflicts with `svn resolve` before committing.

You can also use the `--accept` option:

```
svn merge --accept postpone URL WC
```

This will give essentially the same end result.*

You can suppress the output using the `--quiet` flag.

Unfortunately, the SVN client doesn't treat a merge with conflicts as a failure, so it exits with a zero status. You can run `svn status` after the merge to see if any files are in conflict, e.g.:

```
M       bar
C       foo
D       qux
```

Alternatively, you can try using the [SWIG bindings to the C API](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.developer.usingapi.html), which should allow you to do more granular error checking. There is also [PySVN](http://pysvn.tigris.org/), which is supposedly more Pythonic than the bindings provided by SVN.

---

* I would use `--non-interactive` instead of `--accept` since `--non-interactive` will suppress *all* prompts, not just those for conflicts. For example, if you haven't saved the credentials for the user running your script, `--non-interactive` will cause the merge to fail immediately, while if you use `--accept`, you will be prompted for a password and your script will hang.